# Não consigo executar alguns códigos em C pelo Sublime Text 3

Tags: c, mingw, sublime-text-3

Tenho uma pasta com alguns códigos simples em C, consigo compilar, porém o código não é executado corretamente no terminal do sublime text 3.

Não retorna nenhuma informação ou exibe esta mensagem devido ao código estar em loop:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file teste.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[Finished in 1.2s]
```

Tentei a solução de um problema semelhante ao meu aqui no stack overflow, buscando pelo serviço "Application Experience", porém esse serviço não está aparecendo no meu computador, além do problema ser um pouco diferente.

Estou utilizando a build configurada desta maneira:

```
{
    "cmd" : ["gcc", "$file_name", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe"],
    "selector" : "source.c",
    "shell" : true,
    "working_dir" : "$file_path",

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd" : ["gcc", "$file_name", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe","&&", "${file_base_name}.exe"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Forneça mais detalhes a sua pergunta para ficar mais rica, fale qual IDE você está utilizando, como está utilizando etc..

Comment: Me parece que a mensagem: "cannot open output file teste.exe: Permission denied" é bastante clara. Você está tentando gravar o arquivo "teste.exe" numa pasta para a qual você não tem as devidas permissões.

Comment: Mas como isso explica o fato de que consigo compilar e executar outros códigos em C na mesma pasta, além de outras linguagens como C++ e Python?

Comment: O arquivo deve estar sendo executado em loop. Se for o caso va opções de segurança([CTRL]+[ALT]+[DEL]) selecione o gerenciador de tarefas e procure o seu executável e feche-o.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Acabei de verificar, o código está sendo compilado, é executado, mas não retorna nada e continua em execução, ao rodar o código novamente ocorre o erro de permissão negada. Agora preciso descobrir a razão de não estar retornando nenhuma informação.

Comment: Fiz algumas correções no post, devido ao problema não ter sido identifcado corretamente no início.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após algumas pesquisas e testes, descobri que o terminal do Sublime Text não aceita entradas. Por isto, ao rodar o executável diretamente pelo editor, o programa em linguagem C entra em loop e não consegue exibir nada. Testei removendo as funções de entrada como 'scanf e getchar' na linguagem C e 'input' em um código na linguagem python. No caso da linguagem python, as instruções após o comando de entrada não são exibidos, acredito que esta diferença de como são executados seja devido a uma linguagem ser compilada(C) e a outra interpretada(Python).

A solução que encontrei é executar o programa diretamente no cmd ou powershell.